# Why do these two summations not equate?

Tags: summation

Why is the below equation false?

(1) $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 =  \ (1/4)\sum_{i=0}^{2n} {i}^2 $

When If we let $\ j=2i $ , and substitute $\ i=(j/2)$ into the leftmost equation above, then:

(2) $\sum_{j=0}^{2n} {(j/2)}^2 $

Which gives the same sum as:

$\ (1/4)\sum_{i=0}^{2n} {i}^2$

Note: I know the equation on line (1) is wrong, by actually summing the adjacent summations, but I can't see why this would be so.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{i}{2}$ is an integer implies $j$ must be even, whereas your sum (2) is taken over integers $j$ regardless of odd or even.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the first n natural numbers is given by the formula sum1=n(n+1)(2n+1)/6. Consider the sum of the first 2n natural numbers. Let k=2n. Then by the above formula we have sum2=k(k+1)(2k+1)/6=(2n)(2n+1)(4n+1)/6 on substituting k=2n. Thus sum2 is not equal to (sum1)/4. It is always better to write the formula first and then checking that RHS=LHS. Hope it helps.

Comment: That's the way I solved this. But it's not the answer I'm looking for. Thanks anyways. I was more asking what fundamental property about the rightmost upper equation makes it so that it doesn't equal the leftmost side, when the algebra appears to imply they should be equal.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^n i^2&=0^2+1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+\cdots +n^2\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad  (1)\\
\sum_{j=0}^{2n} (j/2)^2&=\left(\frac 02\right)^2+\left(\frac 12\right)^2+\left(\frac 22\right)^2+\left(\frac 32\right)^2+\left(\frac 42\right)^2\cdots+\cdots +\left(\frac n2\right)^2+\cdots+\left(\frac {2n}2\right)^2\\
&=\frac 14 \left(0^2+1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+\cdots+(2n)^2\right)\\
&=0^2+\left(\frac 12\right)^2+1+\left(\frac 32\right)^2+2^2+\left(\frac 52\right)^2+\cdots+\left(\frac {n-1}2\right)^2+n^2\qquad \qquad (2)\end{align}$$
You can see clearly that $(1)\neq (2)\\$ as well as identify the additional terms in $(2)$.

What you probably wanted was 
$$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2=\frac 14\sum_{i=0}^n (2i)^2$$

---

You might be interested to know that
$$\sum_{i=0}^{2n} i^2=\sum_{i=1}^{2n} i^2=\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^2+(2i)^2$$